# Using vuetify to determine different layouts for different screen sizes

Tags: vue.js, layout, flexbox, vuetify.js

I have a vue.js application and I'm using vuetify. I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

When I shrink the width of the viewport, it ends up looking like this:

[image]

I don't like this view. I'd prefer to have the dropdown be shoved under the row description and have the checkboxes stay aligned with the ones on the other rows, like this:

[image]

The problem is that the order of items in each row goes as follows: description, dropdown (if applicable to row), checkbox 1, checbox 2, checkbox 3. The only way I can see the dropdown falling below the description is if it's put at the end of the row. But can that be done with CSS below certain screen widths?

Here is my code:

```
<v-card class="mb-3 px-3">
      <v-card-title class="px-0">
          <div class="headline">Items</div> 
      </v-card-title>
      <v-container fluid pa-0>
      <v-layout row wrap py-3>
          <v-flex xs9 sm6 md9>
              <v-label>Item</v-label>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 1</v-label></v-flex>
          <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 2</v-label></v-flex>
          <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 3</v-label></v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      </v-container>
      <v-form>
        <v-card v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :id="'index-' + index" flat>
            <v-container fluid pa-0>
                <v-layout row wrap align-center style="min-height: 80px;">
                    <v-flex xs12 sm6 :class="item.hasDropdown ? 'md5' : 'md9'"><p class="pt-3 pb-3 font-weight-medium">{{item.description}}</p></v-flex>
                    <v-flex md4 v-if="item.hasDropdown">
                      <v-select :items="dropdownOptions" v-model="dropdownSelection" outline label="dropdown" class="d-inline-block"></v-select>
                    </v-flex>
                    <v-flex xs4 sm2 md1><label class="hidden-sm-and-up">Col 1:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col1" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
                    <v-flex xs4 sm2 md1><label class="hidden-sm-and-up">Col 2:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col2" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
                    <v-flex xs4 sm2 md1><label class="hidden-sm-and-up">Col 3:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col3" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
                </v-layout>
            </v-container>
            <v-divider v-if="index < items.length - 1"></v-divider>
        </v-card>
      </v-form>
    </v-card>
```

You'll note that I'm using vuetify's flex classes such as sm2, md1, sm2, etc. These are great for adjusting the number of columns on different screen sizes, but is there something similar in vuetify for determining different layouts based on different screen sizes?

Comment: What's the purpose of using v-card components as a table? Maybe v-data-table component will be more appropriate to you? It's very flexible component that based on native HTML <table> tag and I think it'll be much easier to customize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the [order classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids#order-classes) for this purpose. Just add order-lg/order-md etc according to your need. Here in your example i'm using `order-md`. Customize according to your needs. Here's how I have done it:

1. Instead of `v-flex`, you have to use `v-col`
2. for grid use `md=9` style instead of `md9`
3. your page must have `v-app` at root level, otherwise this will not work.

.........................

```
<v-card class="mb-3 px-3">
  <v-card-title class="px-0">
      <div class="headline">Items</div> 
  </v-card-title>
  <v-container fluid pa-0>
    <v-layout row wrap py-3>
      <v-flex xs9 sm6 md9>
          <v-label>Item</v-label>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 1</v-label></v-flex>
      <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 2</v-label></v-flex>
      <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 3</v-label></v-flex>
  </v-layout>
  <v-divider></v-divider>
  </v-container>
  <v-form>
    <v-card v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :id="'index-' + index" flat>
        <v-container fluid pa-0>
            <v-layout row wrap align-center style="min-height: 80px;">
                <v-col xs=12 sm=6 :md="item.hasDropdown ? '5' : '9'"><p class="pt-3 pb-3 font-weight-medium">{{item.description}}</p></v-col>
                <v-col xs=4 sm=2 md=1 order-md="2"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up">Col 1:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col1" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-col>
                <v-col xs=4 sm=2 md=1 order-md="2"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up">Col 2:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col2" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-col>
                <v-col xs=4 sm=2 md=1 order-md="2"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up">Col 3:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col3" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-col>
                <v-col md=4 v-if="item.hasDropdown" order-md="1">
                  <v-select :items="dropdownOptions" v-model="dropdownSelection" outline label="dropdown" class="d-inline-block"></v-select>
                </v-col>
            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
        <v-divider v-if="index < items.length - 1"></v-divider>
    </v-card>
  </v-form>
</v-card>
```

**SOLUTION 2**
Solution 1 is more like vuetifyish way to do the ordering. For plain css way:

```
<v-card class="mb-3 px-3">
  <v-card-title class="px-0">
      <div class="headline">Items</div> 
  </v-card-title>
  <v-container fluid pa-0>
  <v-layout row wrap py-3>
      <v-flex xs9 sm6 md9>
          <v-label>Item</v-label>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 1</v-label></v-flex>
      <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 2</v-label></v-flex>
      <v-flex sm2 md1 class="text-xs-center hidden-xs-only"><v-label>Col 3</v-label></v-flex>
  </v-layout>
  <v-divider></v-divider>
  </v-container>
  <v-form>
    <v-card v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :id="'index-' + index" flat>
        <v-container fluid pa-0>
            <v-layout row wrap align-center style="min-height: 80px;">
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 :class="item.hasDropdown ? 'md5' : 'md9'"><p class="pt-3 pb-3 font-weight-medium">{{item.description}}</p></v-flex>
                <v-flex md4 v-if="item.hasDropdown" class="v-select">
                  <v-select :items="dropdownOptions" v-model="dropdownSelection" outline label="dropdown" class="d-inline-block"></v-select>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs4 sm2 md1 class="v-chkbox"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up">Col 1:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col1" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
                <v-flex xs4 sm2 md1 class="v-chkbox"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up">Col 2:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col2" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
                <v-flex xs4 sm2 md1 class="v-chkbox"><label class="hidden-sm-and-up">Col 3:</label><v-checkbox v-model="item.col3" class="checkbox"></v-checkbox></v-flex>
            </v-layout>
        </v-container>
        <v-divider v-if="index < items.length - 1"></v-divider>
    </v-card>
  </v-form>
</v-card>
```

And Here's the CSS:

```
.v-chkbox {
  order: 1;
}
.v-select {
  order: 2;
}
```

*Don't forget the media query which I didn't add.

** To know more about css ordering check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) and [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/) link.

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks Mishel! I wasn't able to get method #1 to work but method #2 worked like a charm.

Comment: Yep method #1 is mainly for page main layout purposes. Hard to implement inside any component. That's why I added method #2. Happy coding :)